# how can use a range of discriminator values in JPA with the stategy "SINGLE_TABLE"?

Tags: java, jpa

I have a father class called "Banner", and a lot of class who inherit from him.
All the class who start width the same number in the discriminator value, have the same attributes, then I want to use the same class to agrupate them

My actual code is something like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue("20001")
public class IndexGallery extends Banner{
```

But I want something like this, because is more general:

```
....
@DiscriminatorRange("20000-29999")
public class Gallery extends Banner{
....
@DiscriminatorRange("30000-39999")
public class FooBanner extends Banner{
```

By other hand it is posible to create a custom rule to discrimate? like a regular expresion?

Comment: For what purpose is this "grouping" ? The discriminator defines the class that it relates to, not what subclasses it has. If you want to be able to query for all subclasses then that is in the query mechanism not using this flag

Comment: I want to use the discriminator to determine the class. And inside the class I want the same discriminator to determine a ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@DiscriminatorFormula`. Using a person example:

```
@DiscriminatorFormula("case when age is null then 0 else age end")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="person_id")
    private int personId;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="age")
    private Integer age;
}
```

Hibernate has some documentation about it [here.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-discriminator)

Comment: where does the user say he is using Hibernate?

Comment: @NeilStockton I made an assumption ... and I think that hibernate provides a clean (and possibly only) solution for this